# Paypal no-shipping variable not working

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I'm having some trouble implementing PayPal into a website. I haven't used it in a while and a lot of things have changed since.

The problem I'm having is that i specified clearly that users should not be prompted for their shipping address, however, when the "no paypal account" option is selected, the shipping info is anyways asked.

I know I should ask PayPal, but here people are smarter and kinder. =)

code:

*note the: `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">`*

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="ventas@ziced.com">
<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">


<!-- Variables agregadas -->
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notify.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="return.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="cancel_return.php">



<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="primary">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">



<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Ziced id:">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">





<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

`no_shipping=1` applies to the shipping address. What you're looking at for the buyer on the 'guest checkout form' is the billing address. That's always going to be required.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little more information for others:

```
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0"> - prompt for shipping address, but do not require one
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"> - do not prompt for shipping address
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2"> - prompt for shipping address, and require one
```

See also: [Paypal Address Handling Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_BillingShippingAddress)